# How to make a query with multiple relations?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Assuming this :

```rb
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :rowbills, dependent: :destroy
end

class Rowbill < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :invoice, inverse_of: :rowbills
  belongs_to :item
end

class Invoice < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :customer
end

class Customer < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :invoices
end
```

I would like to know if it is possible to start from Items to retrieve certain fields on Rowbills, Invoices and Customers?

I think i should join my tables this way?

```rb
Item.joins(rowbills: {invoice: customer})
```

or

```rb
Item.includes(rowbills: {invoice: customer})
```

Here an extract of the schema.rb (I left only the fields that I would like to recover)

```rb
create_table "items", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
  t.string   "label"
end

create_table "rowbills", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
  t.decimal  "total_price_vat_excluded_cache", precision: 8,  scale: 2, default: "0.0"
  t.integer  "invoice_id"
  t.integer  "item_id"
  t.index ["invoice_id"], name: "index_rowbills_on_invoice_id", using: :btree
  t.index ["item_id"], name: "index_rowbills_on_item_id", using: :btree
end

create_table "invoices", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
  t.integer  "customer_id"
  t.index ["customer_id"], name: "index_invoices_on_customer_id", using: :btree
end

create_table "customers", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
  t.string   "name"
end
```

I would like to browse the items to get something like this at the end :

```json
items: [
  {
    label: "First Item",
    customers: [
      {
        name: "First Customer",
        total_price_vat_excluded_cache: "600.0",
      },
      {
        name: "Second Customer",
        total_price_vat_excluded_cache: "400.0",
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    label: "Second Item",
    customers: [
      {
        name: "First Customer",
        total_price_vat_excluded_cache: "200.0",
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I hope I was clear, thank you in advance to those who can help me.

Answer (score 0):

You want to create indirect assocations that will let you traverse the "tree":

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :rowbills, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :invoices, through: :rowbills
  has_many :customers, through: :invoices
end

class Rowbill < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :invoice, inverse_of: :rowbills
  belongs_to :item
end

class Invoice < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :customer
  has_many :rowbills
  has_many :products, through: :rowbills
end

class Customer < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :invoices
  has_many :items, through: :invoices
end
```

See [the `has_many through:` association](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association).

This lets you get the customers for each item through `item.customers` (just beware of the potential n+1 query).

`Rowbill` also sounds like some kind of duck. The term commonly used is for each line on a order form or invoice is [*line item*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/line_item).

Comment: If there is an issue with n+1, you can use the conditions option, ie `has_many :what_ever, -> {includes(:through_relationship)}, through: :through_relationship`

Comment: @Int'lManOfCodingMystery I didn't want to go into details and drift of topic but you can actually just do `Item.includes(:customers)` and rails will handle including the join table as well.

Comment: Ya, I just meant if they wanted to have that eager loading through the relationship by default. Just an off hand suggestion is all :D

Answer (score -1):

I think `Item.includes(...)` is fine.
And the code match the result for me is like

```rb
  items = Item
            .includes(rowbills: {invoice: customer})
            .map do |it|
              {
                label: it.label,
                customer: it.rowbills.map do |bill|
                  {
                    name: bill.invoice.customer.name,
                    total_price_vat_excluded_cache: bill.total_price_vat_excluded_cache} }
                  }
                end
              }
            end
```

Method "includes" would make eager load for relations